# How to integrate Intel C/C++ compiler kit with other IDEs other than Visual Studio?

Tags: netbeans, codeblocks, codelite, icc, intel-parallel-studio

I have C/C++ compatible IDEs such as,*CODE-BLOCKS*,*CODELITE* and *Netbeans* and I installed latest Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017,I tried to setup compiler settings and linker settings for Intel compiler environment with particular IDE,but all failed to compile  simple source file.

**If someone knows how to setup Intel C/C++ compiler with one of above mentioned IDEs please respond.**

Do I have to follow special rules? when set up Intel compiler environment other than setting compiler option and linker settings?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem as I wanted to use the intel compiler from within Netbeans Ide (8.2) on Linux System  64-bit Ubuntu 16.4.

Just do the following:

From *tools/options* choose *add...* and then put on the base directory the place where you installed the intel toosl. In my case it was */opt/intel/bin*.

It will automatically detect the other tools except for make and assembler tools and then choose default and then apply.